# CreateProcess application not found in cache c++ MFC

Tags: c++, createprocess

i am writing a simple program which calls CreateProcess thousands of times, so its taking a while to run. in my output windows i'm seeing this message each time

```
application "whatever.exe" not found in cache
```

i call CreateProcess like this

```
BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL, g_minicapcmd,
        NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
    if (!result)   {
            LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
            DWORD dw = GetLastError();
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
                        NULL, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

            CString strError = (LPTSTR) lpMsgBuf;
            TRACE(_T("::executeCommandLine() failed at CreateProcess()\nCommand=%s\nMessage=%s\n\n"), g_minicapcmd, strError);
            LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
            return false;
    } else {
            // Successfully created the process.  Wait for it to finish.
            WaitForSingleObject( processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE );

            // Close the handles.
            CloseHandle( processInformation.hProcess );
            CloseHandle( processInformation.hThread );

    }
```

is there a way to get it to cache or some way to make it faster? i already tried putting the .exe its loading on ramdisk and that helped a bit

Comment: The top Google result for "application not found in cache" is *this question*. Are you sure *your program* isn't printing it?

Comment: i can see it generated as i step over CreateProcess